# Chef cookbook for installing mongodb-shell only

Tags: mongodb, chef-infra, mongodb-shell

I am trying to install a mongo client via chef.  Essentially this is what I have been doing in manual installs:

```
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo 

    [mongodb]
    name=MongoDB Repository
    baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
    gpgcheck=0
    enabled=1

sudo yum install mongodb-org-shell-2.6.7
```

I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, nor do I want to install anything other than the shell. This cookbook looks like a good resource, but I cannot get it to install just the shell:

```
https://github.com/edelight/chef-mongodb
```

But it seems to not allow for any of the main components to be installed.  Will i need to LWRP?

Answer (score 0):

Well i picked apart the mongodb cookbook - to this tune:

```
yum_repository 'mongodb-org-3.0' do
  description 'mongodb RPM Repository'
  baseurl "http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.0/#{node['kernel']['machine']  =~ /x86_64/ ? 'x86_64' : 'i686'}"
  action :create
  gpgcheck false
  enabled true
end  


case node['platform_family']
when 'debian'
  # this options lets us bypass complaint of pre-existing init file
  # necessary until upstream fixes ENABLE_MONGOD/DB flag
  packager_opts = '-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes'
when 'rhel'
  # Add --nogpgcheck option when package is signed
  # see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8770
  packager_opts = '--nogpgcheck'
else
  packager_opts = ''
end


package node[:frt_mongodb][:package_name] do
  options packager_opts
  action :install
  version node[:frt_mongodb][:package_version]
end
```

That said it looks like I should be able to use that cookbook configured with the right attributes to aCcomplish this.  The biggest problem is that the recipe within manipulates files that aren't necessary for the shell.